# Is there a more advanced keyboard teleop controller for pr2

Tags: ros, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a `keyboard teleoperation program` in pr2_teleop package. But it only provides very basic movement on the base. I am writing a more advanced keyboard controller, just like the `Joystick teleoperation controller` did, but I was wondering if there is already some similar keyboard controller there to save my work~
Anyone knows this? Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10862/is-there-a-more-advanced-keyboard-teleop-controller-for-pr2/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a more advanced teleop package for the PR2 called [pr2_teleop_general](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_teleop_general). That allows you to control the arms, head and base.

---

Originally posted by [cmansley](https://answers.ros.org/users/803/cmansley/) with karma: 198 on 2011-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-08-09**:
thank  you~

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also, if you're willing to use a GUI to control the PR2, you can try the new interactive pr2 marker control program for teleop:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_marker_control

---

Originally posted by [Matt Klingensmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/942/matt-klingensmith/) with karma: 141 on 2011-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-08-11**:
cool! will check that out, thanks!